# I'd like to make search page

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, search-engine

I'm going to make search page in website using google search engine.

I'm using laravel 5.4 framework.

So I got the Google Custom Search API key.

And I created new google search engine here.
[image: creating search engine]

I got the search engine ID.

And I used "jan-drda/laravel-google-custom-search-engine" package for searching.

I can get the search result. but result is limited to lists of url that I 
inserted in custom search engine.

How can I get the result same as google search result?

In other words, how can I search without searching url limitation.

I hope that make sense.

Comment: I guess that the Google Custom SearchEngine uses your site data indexed by Google, so if you're developing locally, you will just get the results that you put in your Google App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the urls entered in "Sites to Search" from and you will have the search returned from whole web.

Note: The results on main google search and results via google API, results would still vary.

Comment: thank you for helping me.
but when I remove all the urls from "sites to search field".
I could not get any results.

Comment: Right next to where the "Sites to Search" is written, there is a dropdown select the value "Search the Entire Web".. currently it must be search only included sites

Comment: Oh, you are great!
Thank you for helping me.
resolved this problem.
Thank you sir!

Comment: One more thing!
Can I get the auto list string like google.
I mean, searching candidate string.

Comment: @hkg328 not sure about that thing, sorry.

Comment: Hi, how do resolve daily limitation.
I have to purchase custom search API key or search engine id?